# Accessing Graphics from Different Methods?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I'm trying to access the variable "g" from a different method, it does not throw an error but doesn't write to the screen. Any way to use the graphics class from different methods? Paint Method:

```
public static Graphics g;

private void paintClass(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
   e.Graphics = g;
}
```

Method Im Trying To Access "g" From:

```
public void drawline(){
    g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.AliceBlue), 10, 10, 20, 20);
}
```

**Note These Code Snippets Are from The Same Class**

If this isn't possible, I am just trying to figure out a way to paint to the screen from a method that isn't the paint method.

Comment: Graphic would have to come from a bitmap to do that.

Comment: You can write functions and feed in a Graphics object. It can be from a Paint event to draw onto the screen or from a Bitmap to draw into this bitmap. A nice use would be to create complex graphics and when you are happy call the same methods with a Graphics object created from a bitmap to save the stuff to a file .  The code you show make little sense imo. Do not try to store/cache the e.Graphics obejct as it will be invalid after the Paint event!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing it, pass it directly from your event:

```
private void paintClass(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
   drawline(e.Graphics);
}

public void drawline(Graphics g){
    g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.AliceBlue), 10, 10, 20, 20);
}
```

This approach would make more sense if the "draw" method was part of a different class. For example, if you had a collection of custom class instances and you pass the graphics to each one so they can each draw themselves onto a surface (with the graphics provided from the paint event of that surface).

Comment: `I am just trying to figure out a way to paint to the screen from a method that isn't the paint method`  :-)

Comment: @LarsTech Then this meets the requirement, as it technically isn't the Paint event.  We both know what they are looking for is `CreateGraphics()`, but we both also know that isn't the correct approach. ;)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is that every time you call something like the `drawline()` method that you mention in your post, add this action to a `List`. Then, when the `List` changes, have your paint class fire a `Refresh` event that the containing control can use to ensure the canvas will be invalidated. When the control calls `Refresh()` on itself, the `OnPaint` override is called and the items in the list are iterated and drawn (or in some cases redrawn) in a legitimate Graphics context that doesn't rely on the temporary fix of calling `CreateGraphics` ad hoc. You could then make these calls from your main form:

---

**Diag Button** *- Diagonal line adding 25 to offset each time.*

```
private void buttonDiag_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _paintClass.DrawDiagonal(GetNextTestColor(), offsetX: 25 * _testCountDiag++);
}
```

Clicking the button 3x executes the `Drawline` with a different random known color each time.

[image: color diagonals]

---

**Line Button** *- Draw a line between two points.*

```
private void buttonLine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var offsetY = 15 * _testCountLine++;
    _paintClass.Drawline(
        GetNextTestColor(),
        new PointF(0, 100 + offsetY),
        new PointF(ClientRectangle.Width, 100 + offsetY));
}
```

[image: add 3x horizontal lines]

---

**Under the hood**

The `PaintClass` inherits `List<PaintClassContext>` where:

```
class PaintClassContext
{
    public PaintOp PaintOp { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public PointF Start { get; set; }
    public PointF End { get; set; }
    public float OffsetX { get; set; }
    public float OffsetY { get; set; }
}
enum PaintOp{ DrawLine, Clear, DrawDiagonal}
```

**Example: Implementation of `DrawDiagonal`**

Add a new context to the current list.

```
public void DrawDiagonal(Color color, float offsetX = 0, float offsetY = 0) =>
    Add(new PaintClassContext
    {
        PaintOp = PaintOp.DrawDiagonal,
        Color = color,
        OffsetX = offsetX,
        OffsetY = offsetY,
    });
```

Every time a new action is added, the `Refresh` event is fired and this repaints the canvas.

```
public new void Add(PaintClassContext context)
{
    base.Add(context);
    _modified = true;
    Refresh?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

---

The `MainForm` will be subscribed to the `PaintClass.Refresh` event and calls Refresh().

```
_paintClass.Refresh += (sender, e) =>
{
    // Causes the control to repaint.
    Refresh();
    Text = CurrentTestColor.ToString();
};
```

This causes the control to redraw, where the `PaintAll` will iterate its current items and paint them in a legitimate graphics context rather than trying to "finesse" one.

```
PaintClass _paintClass = new PaintClass();
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    _paintClass.PaintAll(e.Graphics, always: false);
}
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/paint-class.git) this prototype.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you could obtain what you want by using `CreateGraphics()`.

```
var g = myButton.CreateGraphics();
g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, 0, 0, 20, 20);
```

Replace myButton with the `Control` or `Form` you want to draw on.

This may turn out to not be the right approach though. The drawing will disappear e.g. when the form is minimized, maximized, gets covered by another form etc.

The recommended pattern is to use the `Paint` event - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.paint?view=windowsdesktop-6